# '&&' and '||' vs '? :'

Tags: javascript, syntax, ternary-operator

Why would you use this syntax?

```
var myVar = myArray.length && myArray || myObject;
```

instead of

```
var myVar = myArray.length ? myArray : myObject;
```

Edit: I just had a thought that if in the case of the `&& ||` syntax both sides of the `||` evaluated to false, as you might expect if `myObject` was `undefined` or `null`, if false would be returned. But it isn't, the objects value `undefined` or `null` is returned.

```
true  ||  true      //true
true  ||  false     //true
false ||  true      //true
false ||  false     //false
```

Edit2:

```
!!(myArray.length ? myArray : myObject);
```

This does however return false if `myObject` is `undefined` or `null`

Comment: Because you're used to programming in a language that doesn't support ternary conditionals. Don't do it!

Comment: Because there is more than one way to skin a cat

Comment: Personally I'd resort to more robust array checking.  For instance `var myArray = [];` fails this test...

Comment: ... because you want everyone to lose 10-15 seconds of their lives figuring out what the heck it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks -- what?  Javascript does have the ternary op.

Comment: @Malvolio: Maybe I phrased that poorly. I know, I meant that the person who wrote the first line is probably coming from a language that doesn't have it, so he's using conventions that don't make sense in JavaScript.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks -- I misread "used to" as "using".

Comment: Perhaps because someone is learning `&&` and `||` and has not reached `? :` yet.

Comment: @pimvdb: someone who's come up with such use of boolean operators, but didn't reach the ternary operator yet has been following really strange learning path

Comment: To turn truthy/falsy into true/false, use !!expr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x && y || z` is *different* than `x ? y : z` even if it "works" in the case presented.

Consider when `y` evaluates to a false-value (in the post `y` can't be a false-value when it is evaluated because it is dependent upon `x` and thus it "works" as expected).

Using `?:` is the much better and more clear construct in this case. The only reason I can give for using the other syntax is "too much cleverness".

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but what do you mean by *"in the post y can't be a false-value because it is dependent upon x..."*? Do you mean it can't be false assuming you know you have an Array?

Comment: @patrick dw `x` is myArray.length and `y` is myArray. Thus `y` will *never* be a false-value if myArray.length is a true-value. (myArray will either be an Array/Object, which is not a false-value, or non-Empty string, which is not a false-value). It's not so much being dependent, so much as being dependent in a very particular manner, as is this case.

Comment: *"...if myArray.length is a true-value..."* Alrighty, that makes more sense to me. "Falsey" values that don't reject a property lookup was what I had in mind. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

A ternary is the only correct thing to do here, unless you guarantee that `myObject.name` has a "true" value.

Consider

```
res = a ? b : c;
```

vs.

```
res = a && b || c;
```

What is the difference? The first does what it is supposed to. But the second tests `a`. If `a` is false, it gets `c`, as the ternary version.

But if `a` is true, it only gets `b` if this is true as well, if not, it gets `c`, what is not wanted at all.

Answer (score 1):

Tastes vary.  Maybe somebody just got in the habit of writing things like

```
var myName = myObject && myObject.name || "unknown";
```

and stuck with it even when a ternary would work as well.

Comment: This is actually one case where it might work "better" than a `?:`. Consider when myObject is "hello"; should myName be `"unknown"` (as it would be above) of `undefined` if using a ternary?

Comment: That's what I mean: in many cases, the ternary op lacks the power you need.  Then when it *would* suffice, you're no longer used to using it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsperf.com/conditional-operators

It looks like you use `&& ||` when you want your code to go slower and you want to obfuscate it a little more :)

---

There's also a difference between what is going on.

```
foo && bar || foobar  // if foo or bar is false, then foobar will be returned
foo?bar:foobar        // the bar, or foobar, is decided solely on foo
```

---

If you wanted the ternary to act like the logical conditional it would be:

```
foo&&bar?bar:foobar
```